# JQuery Disable Dynamically Created Html Button in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

A button in my view needs to be created depending on a state.

Index.cshtml:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#send_request_button").on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "SendRequest",
                method: "GET",
            }).done(function (request_result) {
                if (request_result != null && request_result == '1') {
                    alert("Attempting button disabling");
                    @*attempt 1*@
                    @*$(this).prop("disabled", true);*@
                    @*attempt 2*@
                    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }else {
                    alert("Could not disable Button");
                }
            });
        });    
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
        @{
        if (ViewBag.ButtonFlag != null && ViewBag.ButtonFlag)
        {
            Response.Write("<text id=\"send_request_text\"></text>");
            Response.Write("<input id=\"send_request_button\" type=\"button\" value=\"Send Insert Request\"/>");
        }
      }
    }
</body>
</html>
```

This is giving the button correctly and it is clicked, the expected result after the successful jquery ajax, which is in this case 1, is received. But none of the two attempts to disable the dynamic button is producing the expected result.

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: Try with `$("#send_request_button").attr("disabled", true);`

Comment: is it showing "Attempting button disabling" alert message?

Comment: @Ajay: Alert message is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of $(this) use element id to select in done() It is because the scope of using 'this' keyword won't be available if used in other function:

```
 $("#send_request_button").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "SendRequest",
            method: "GET",
        }).done(function (request_result) {
            if (request_result != null && request_result == '1') {
                alert("Attempting button disabling");
                @*attempt 1*@
                @*$(this).prop("disabled", true);*@
                @*attempt 2*@
                $("#send_request_button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }else {
                alert("Could not disable Button");
            }
        });
    });
```